# Android:send sms through internet without using native services

Tags: android, sms

I am making an app in which i am have to send sms to another device using internet but i donot want to use phone native means i donot want to pay for sms i.e. i want to use internet to send messages .Is their any other way than sending xml to server and if used xml then how to maintain session. Can anyone help me .Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to use any of the online SMS service and use their API (You may have to pay it). The one that comes to my mind is http://www.sendsms.pk

Comment: i donot want to pay.I want that my app should use internet service and send messages to other person

Comment: If you don't want to pay just send an email.